# rotating list with slideup and slide down buttons

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I should probably indicate first that i am quite new to jquery firstly so my code might not be to great. What i am trying to achieve is to have a list of items rotate automatically, and also be controlled by the user, with two separate buttons which have slideup and slidedown functionalities respectively. I have already made an attempt  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m9QGb/2/) by having the list rotate but not quite sure how to add the buttons to make the list slide up and down...

Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) plugin.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am not looking for a plugin, i would like to extend my code as specified above..